# Translate image using PHP GD library

Tags: php, png, gd

I want to translate the images through PHP. For example, if an image is at bottom right, I need to move it to top left. Size is 16x16 and inside the transparent 16x16 canvas there is an image.

[image: For example]

I want to move this image from bottom to top by calculating its position first. Can this be done with GD? or do I need any other lib as IMagic.

At the end , I want to merge two images, but the 2nd image is also at bottom right, so if I merge both its going to be an overlap, I need to decide where one to move the image.

Comment: Normally you'd use some of the GD functions to determine the position of what you want to move on the canvas, then do math on PHP to calculate the new coordinates.

Comment: I can't understand exactly what you need. Try to be more specific and provide more detail and a clear description of what you want and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I need to crop the non transparent part of a 16x16 transparent canvas. Then the cropped image, I want to add to top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right corners of the 16x16 canvas. So that, I can add overlays on top of it.